# Updated AuthenicationPhoneNumber using Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to update the AuthenicationPhoneNumber using the B2C graph api? If not is there any programmatic way of updating this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not supported to Add/Update Authentication Phone Number via graph api or do that programmatically.

See this similar issue: [Azure B2C - Add/Update Authentication Contact Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46463700/azure-b2c-add-update-authentication-contact-info).

Also, see the reply of AAD Team in this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/14795625-authentication-phone):

> **Dec 8, 2017** We are building an API that will allow you to get and set credential information (i.e. Authentication Phone, Authentication Email, etc.) for both multi-factor authentication (MFA) and self-service password reset (SSPR). We will keep you updated when this becomes available.
>
> **March 1, 2019**  Hi folks! The work for this feature is still in progress. We will update you when it is available. Thank you for your patience!

According to the reply, the API to access the Authentication Phone may come soon, just wait for it.